# Background worker, updated version - how does old process exit?

Tags: appharbor

When I deploy a new version of a background worker how does the old worker exit?  It the process killed?  Is there some kind of graceful termination option?

Comment: I think we currently use `TerminateProcess`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks! could you add as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

friism is correct, right now the process is forcefully terminated using `TerminateProcess`.